# How to handle long text xamarin.ios

Tags: xamarin.ios

I need to show a long string in a label that is having 3 lines.

this is what I need to show

[image]

```
myLabel.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.MiddleTruncation;
```

how can i avoid getting a character after the 3 dots?

[image]

Comment: Use TailTruncation so you don't have anything after the ... dots.

`myLabel.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.TailTruncation;`

Comment: but I need to add "Tap here to see more" string after the dots, in the same line as I showed here. is there any way to do that?

Comment: @Ranwala Have you solved your issues?

Answer (score 0):

When you set the `MyLabel.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.MiddleTruncation;` it will cut your string at middle position without detecting whether it is a whole word. It is by design.

If you do want to achieve your effect, we can try to customize the string. Firstly calculate the string's height, then cut it off from the last position when we find the height fitting the label's height which has three lines. Set the label's text to the substring we just get.

```
string descriptionStr = "... Tap here to see all.";

MyLabel.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.CharacterWrap;
//Get the real label's height
View.LayoutIfNeeded();

int stringCount = MyLabel.Text.Length;
for (int i = MyLabel.Text.Length; i > 0; i--)
{
    //Customize the strings
    var str = new NSString(MyLabel.Text.Substring(0, i) + descriptionStr);

    //Calculate the height of the string
    var attributes = new NSDictionary(UIStringAttributeKey.Font,
                        MyLabel.Font);
    UIStringAttributes attrib = new UIStringAttributes(attributes);
    var strRect = str.GetBoundingRect(new CGSize(MyLabel.Frame.Width, 0), NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, attrib, null);

    //When we find the height fitting the request, get the string
    if (strRect.Height < MyLabel.Frame.Height)
    {
        stringCount = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

At last we can use the strings:

```
MyLabel.Text = MyLabel.Text.Substring(0, stringCount) + descriptionStr;
```

But when the label's width is not larger enough, we need to cut more characters to fit the label's height. This may be not perfect, but we can set a constant to adjust it:

```
MyLabel.Text = MyLabel.Text.Substring(0, stringCount - constant) + descriptionStr;
```